# How to convert the column values to percentage

Tags: r

I have a csv file as follows.

```
Student Name    English     Evs         Mathematics
                Term 1     Term 1       Term 1  
             Score (150)   Score (150)  Score (150) 
Abhinav.S        107.75    117.25         95.5  
Abhishek.C        112.5    88.75          91    
Aditya              117    116.5          98
```

I need to convert this to percentage without disturbing the dataset, Formula is (obtained score/total score)*100.

I tried all the possible approaches I could, But couldn't do. Could someone help me in finding the logic?

Comment: Use `read.csv()` and then multiply the resulting data frame by `0.6666` or `2/3`.  Reading in your file could be messy because of the way it's formatted, and you might want to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks Tim,  But I have 20 csv files with different maximum scores. Its difficult to hardcode it right?

Comment: Do all the files have three leading lines?  Do they all have four columns separated by whitespace, the first containing names and latter three containing data?

Comment: Yeah Tim, All the Files are with same structure except the change in maximum scores

Comment: Can you put a 'dput' of your data?

Comment: Use `read.table` and, skip the first 3 lines, then use `read.table` again, and read only the 3rd line, extract the numbers with string functions like `gsub` and parse them with `as.integer`. See help for `read.table`, `gsub` and `as.integer` for further reference.

Comment: Tried even this, I got an error as non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Ah there's probably much typecasting, parsing to do, not the easyest thing, but see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following script reads in your input file, and creates a data frame containing the last three rows, which contain your numeric data.  After rescaling the scores to a 100% scale, it creates an output file with the updated values.  The formatting in the output file may not line up exactly.

```
all_content = readLines("filein.txt")
temp_content <- all_content[4:6]

dat = read.table(textConnection(temp_content), header = FALSE,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep="")

> dat
          V1     V2     V3   V4
1  Abhinav.S 107.75 117.25 95.5
2 Abhishek.C 112.50  88.75 91.0
3     Aditya 117.00 116.50 98.0

dat[1:3, 2:4] <- dat[1:3, 2:4] * (2/3)    # convert to percentage

> dat
          V1       V2       V3       V4
1  Abhinav.S 71.83333 78.16667 63.66667
2 Abhishek.C 75.00000 59.16667 60.66667
3     Aditya 78.00000 77.66667 65.33333

# write out the first three lines to an output file
output <- file("fileout.txt")
writeLines(c(all_content[1], all_content[2], all_content[3]), output)
close(output)

# write out the updated data frame as the last three lines
write.table(dat, file="fileout.txt", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE,
            row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, thats again for a single file right? If I need to process 20 files I need to change the fraction 20 times.

Comment: You can set up a simple loop which will iterate over the required number of files.  You might want to put my code into a function.

Comment: Yes, but if you read the comments carefully, you need to extract different points for 100% for each file, this is missing from your answer.

Comment: I see nothing in the comments regarding your point.  My assumption is that he wants to end up with the same number of files, only that the scores have been renormalized to a 100 scale.  Feel free to post your own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that extracts the maximum scores form your file, you'll might have to change the regular expression in the `gsub` or the way you read your file, according to the format of your data.

```
# read fixed width formatted file
test <- read.fwf("test.csv", widths=c(13, 25-13, 39-25, 52-39))

# use first 3 rows as header, convert to character, extract numbers
header <- test[3, 2:4]
header <- lapply(header, as.character)
scores <- as.numeric(gsub("Score \\((.*)\\)", "\\1", header))

# use rest of dataset as data
data <- test[4:nrow(test), ]
data <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)

# divide by max score (you'll might want to do this in a loop/lapply)
data$V2percent <- 100*as.numeric(data$V2)/scores[1]
data$V3percent <- 100*as.numeric(data$V3)/scores[2]
data$V4percent <- 100*as.numeric(data$V4)/scores[3]
```

Comment: Are you certain that hardcoding field widths will work, as in practice the widths may be variable?

Comment: what exactly is not working? can you give the output of the first line (reading the document)?